# UTF-8 & ISO-8859-1 not working for decoding European charset in Java

Tags: java, string, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

Hi I have an HTML page from which I am scrapping data. The page uses UTF-8 charset and contains German and other European letters

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

But when I'm trying to decode it as `ISO-8859-1` and `UTF-8` in Java but nothing really works. I'm not able to get the European Characters instead I get values like:

```
Bayern MÃ¼nchen
Bor. MÃ¶nchengladbach
JÃ©rÃ´me Boateng
```

Following is the piece of my code:

```
               URL myUrl = new URL("http://www.weltfussball.de/spielplan/bundesliga-"
                                + season + "-spieltag/" + gameDay + "/");

    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myUrl.openStream(), "ISO-8859-1"));

                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    all += line;
                }
```

One thing that I have noticed is when I print `String line;` it correctly prints all the Latin Characters on the java console, but as soon as I concatenate it to `String all;` the characters mess up... Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: If the page uses UTF-8, why do you try and read it using ISO-8859-1?

Comment: Also, are you sure it's not your _console_ which cannot display UTF-8 properly?

Comment: I also tried using UTF-8, didn't work aswell. I thought the words are Latin so ISO-Latin should solve the problem but it didn't.

Comment: I am sure. I am not viewing it in my console. I debug the code and view the state of the object, there I could see the String which is not in the correct letters.

Comment: UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 are both character codings; and they are incompatible with one another for such characters. You can't use one for the other.

Comment: I did use UTF-8 decoder as I said before but it did not work

Comment: Try and use the code in my answer; if it doesn't return an error then my suspiscion that it's your display at fault will turn out to be correct

Comment: post your full code, using simply UTF-8 worked for me

Answer (score 0):

First, try and see whether the page *really* uses UTF-8 as it pretends it does:

```
final CharsetDecoder decoder = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newDecoder()
    .onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);

try (
    final InputStream in = url.openStream();
    final Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, decoder);
) {
    /* read the contents */
}
```

If this program throws a `MalformedInputException` then you know the page is lying.

Given your output however, I suspect the problem is that your *display* does not read UTF-8 correctly.

Comment: So the problem is with whatever you use to display the contents. Is this notepad by any chance?

Comment: I am not displaying it yet anywhere. I just see it in the eclipse while debugging. I hover over my object and can see it's state.

Comment: ARGH, STOP! I have made an error in the code snippet; it should have been `REPORT` and not `REPLACE`. Sorry :/ Can you try again?

Comment: I tried again as soon as you edited your comment, still no exception.

Comment: Well, if you still have the display problem, this is really a problem with Eclipse then. Can you try and dump the `.toString()` to a file and read it using an UTF-8 capable editor?

Comment: I have. Still the same result as Bayern MÃ¼nchen and Bor. MÃ¶nchengladbach

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69247/discussion-between-bilal-hasan-and-fge).

Answer (score 0):

This always works.

`InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(myUrl); 
 byte[] b = new byte[is.available()];
 int l = is.read(b);
 String body = new String(b, 0, l, "UTF-8"); // whatever your charset you want`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the **"ISO-8859-1"** is the **only  being read**. Otherwise it isn't going to work.
I had the same problem today, I took out 30 mins to read this article http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html  and then I solved my problem and now I know what is decoded, why people use this, why this is good and the limitations of himself.

To solve my problem I only replaced this tag in my **Header Template file**:

> meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"

FOR:

> meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"

Reload the browser and my European names with weirds characters were now being printed properly :)

***Sorry for bad english!***